# How does one start drawing electric fields?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

How does one start drawing electric fields.you are given two charge.now there are infinite electric field lines so how do you show greater electric field by drawing denser lines.After all there can be infinite lines in between.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82536/2451 and links therein.

Comment: i edited it please see