# Uniform electric field lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

in the case of uniform electric field why should electric field lines  be equally spaced? Is this related to advanced math stuff?

Comment: Related question: [Why does the density of electric field lines make sense, if there is a field line through every point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82536/179151)

Comment: Related question with similar answer: [Electric field line density : Theory vs Reality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493932/179151)

Answer (score 2):

Electric field lines are drawn typically for two reasons: to either show the direction of force a positively charged particle would feel if placed at that point, or to show the strength of the electric field at a given point in comparison to another point. If the line density is greater in one region than in another, the author/artist is typically trying to convey that the electric field is strong there. A *uniform* electric field is, by definition, the same strength and direction everywhere. Meaning, the line density and direction of each electric field line should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are an *infinite* number of “field lines”. One passes through every point. People draw a few of them, uniformly spaced, for a uniform field to indicate that the field is uniform. Otherwise, the field would look non-uniform.

“Field lines” are just a visual aid. Physically, there *are* no “lines in the field”. The field is really a *vector*, with a magnitude and a direction, *at every point.* The “lines” show you the direction of the vectors. The spacing of the lines gives you some sense of the magnitude of the vectors. Closer lines mean larger magnitude.

Comment: In a nice three dimensional sketch, the density of field lines should be proportional to the field strength.