# What exactly is electric flux?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, terminology, gauss-law

I have seen plenty of definitions and descriptions of electric flux.  Most of them say it is the number of field lines per unit area.

However how can there be a fixed number of field lines in a unit area?

If we take an area in an electric field,  there exists a field at every point.(A simple scenario).

Thus in that area there are infinitely many field lines right?

Also if we take into account the curvatures of the field lines, then I could see that there is a difference.  But numerically, there are still infinite lines in that area right?

What am I thinking incorrectly? Please help me as I am unable to wrap my head around this topic

Comment: Related: [Why does the density of electric field lines make sense, if there is a field line through every point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82536/238167)

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.